# Group data by category and date with total by date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to do the following:

1. Group by date, then total number of upvotes and total number of downvotes
2. Group by Category then aggregation has to be done by total number of upvote of all category and downvote of all category by each day upvotes and down votes of individual dates.

Here is my code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
                                $unwind: '$votes'
                            }, {
                                $match: {
                                    'category_id': array[i]
                                }
                            }, {
                                $group: {
                                    _id:'$votes.date',
                                    "category_id": {
                                        $first: "$category_id"
                                    },
                                    up_vote: {
                                        $sum: {
                                            $cond: [{
                                                '$gt': ['$votes.score', 0]
                                            }, "$votes.score", 0]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    down_vote: {
                                        $sum: {
                                            $cond: [{
                                                '$lt': ['$votes.score', 0]
                                            }, "$votes.score", 0]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "$group": {
                                    "_id": "$_id",
                                    "categories": {
                                        "$push": {
                                            "category_id": "$category_id",
                                            "up_vote ": "$up_vote",
                                            "down_vote": "$down_vote"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "total_up_vote": {
                                        $sum: {
                                            $cond: [{
                                                '$lt': ['$votes.score', 0]
                                            }, "$votes.score", 0]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "total_down_vote": {
                                        "$sum": "$down_vote"
                                    }
                                }
                            }{
                                "$unwind": "$categories"
                            },
                            {
                                "$project": {
                                    "category_id": "$categories.category_id",
                                    "down_vote": "$categories.down_vote",
                                    "down_vote_Percentage": {
                                        "$multiply": [{ "$divide": [ "$categories.down_vote", "$total_down_vote" ] },
                                            100
                                        ]
                                    },
                                     "up_vote": "$categories.up_vote",
                                    "up_vote_Percentage": {
                                        "$multiply": [{ "$divide": [ "$categories.down_vote", "$total_total_up_vote" ] },
                                            100
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }

                           }
                            ], function(err, results) {
        res.send(result)
        })
```

This is my database structure:

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("590f1ab8a45e6eb418be32cd"),
        "category_id" : "singer",
        "celebrity_id" : ObjectId("591e71884e743d8015fd1ae0"),
        "user_id" : "591e81277bd0b65c141e64be",
        "votes" : [
                {
                        "date" : "2017/4/7",
                        "score" : -1
                },
                {
                        "date" : "2017/4/19",
                        "score" : -1
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59204135dab356f410d1b8a6"),
        "category_id" : "actor",
        "celebrity_id" : ObjectId("591e80e47bd0b65c141e64bc"),
        "user_id" : "591974b64abd73701dc7c4aa",
        "votes" : [
                {
                        "date" : "2017/4/20",
                        "score" : 1
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5920415cdab356f410d1b8a7"),
        "category_id" : "actor",
        "celebrity_id" : ObjectId("591e81177bd0b65c141e64bd"),
        "user_id" : "591974b64abd73701dc7c4aa",
        "votes" : [
                {
                        "date" : "2017/4/20",
                        "score" : 1
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: This is horribly worded and not presented that well either. I think you mean the total of upvotes and downvotes per category on a given date, and the percentage per category of the daily totals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$votes" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
       "date": "$votes.date",
       "category_id": "$category_id",
    },
    "upvote": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [ { "$gt": [ "$votes.score", 0 ] }, 1, 0 ]
      }
    },
    "downvote": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [ { "$lt": [ "$votes.score", 0 ] }, 1, 0 ]
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.date",
    "categories": {
      "$push": {
        "category": "$_id.category_id",
        "upvote": "$upvote",
        "downvote": "$downvote"
      }
    },
    "total_upvote": { "$sum": "$upvote" },
    "total_downvote": { "$sum": "$downvote" }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$categories" },
  { "$project": {
    "category": "$categories.category",
    "upvote": "$categories.upvote",
    "upvote_percent": {
      "$multiply": [
        { "$divide": [ 
          "$categories.upvote", 
          { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$total_upvote", 0 ]}, 1, "$total_upvote" ] }
        ]},
        100
      ]
    },
    "downvote": "$categories.downvote",
    "downvote_percent": {
      "$multiply": [
        { "$divide": [ 
          "$categories.downvote", 
          { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$total_downvote", 0 ]}, 1, "$total_downvote" ] }
        ]},
        100
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Remembering that as a "pipeline", the view of the document of each stage is equal to how the document was output from the previous stage.

---

**Source data**

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("590f1ab8a45e6eb418be32cd"),
        "category_id" : "singer",
        "celebrity_id" : ObjectId("591e71884e743d8015fd1ae0"),
        "user_id" : "591e81277bd0b65c141e64be",
        "votes" : [
                {
                        "date" : "2017/4/7",
                        "score" : -1
                },
                {
                        "date" : "2017/4/19",
                        "score" : -1
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59204135dab356f410d1b8a6"),
        "category_id" : "actor",
        "celebrity_id" : ObjectId("591e80e47bd0b65c141e64bc"),
        "user_id" : "591974b64abd73701dc7c4aa",
        "votes" : [
                {
                        "date" : "2017/4/20",
                        "score" : 1
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5920415cdab356f410d1b8a7"),
        "category_id" : "actor",
        "celebrity_id" : ObjectId("591e81177bd0b65c141e64bd"),
        "user_id" : "591974b64abd73701dc7c4aa",
        "votes" : [
                {
                        "date" : "2017/4/20",
                        "score" : 1
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5923c7fdbcc8728a67bcc653"),
        "category_id" : "actor",
        "celebrity_id" : ObjectId("591e81177bd0b65c141e64bd"),
        "user_id" : "591974b64abd73701dc7c4aa",
        "votes" : [
                {
                        "date" : "2017/4/20",
                        "score" : -11
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5923d1b9bcc8728a67bcc655"),
        "category_id" : "blip",
        "celebrity_id" : ObjectId("591e81177bd0b65c141e64bd"),
        "user_id" : "591974b64abd73701dc7c4aa",
        "votes" : [
                {
                        "date" : "2017/4/20",
                        "score" : -11
                }
        ]
}
```

**Output**

```js
{
        "_id" : "2017/4/19",
        "category" : "singer",
        "upvote" : 0,
        "upvote_percent" : 0,
        "downvote" : 1,
        "downvote_percent" : 100
}
{
        "_id" : "2017/4/7",
        "category" : "singer",
        "upvote" : 0,
        "upvote_percent" : 0,
        "downvote" : 1,
        "downvote_percent" : 100
}
{
        "_id" : "2017/4/20",
        "category" : "blip",
        "upvote" : 0,
        "upvote_percent" : 0,
        "downvote" : 1,
        "downvote_percent" : 50
}
{
        "_id" : "2017/4/20",
        "category" : "actor",
        "upvote" : 2,
        "upvote_percent" : 100,
        "downvote" : 1,
        "downvote_percent" : 50
}
```

Comment: @Niel Lunn: upvote_percentage is not returning. So that the whole response is displaying as null, when i checked, i came to no the issue was with total_upvote, if i replace with total down_vote then its displaying some results

Comment: @RakshithaT.R I spotted the logic error here. There was I typo and it really needs to be the total votes for the day considered in the percentages. Corrected, and added a short sample data and output

Comment: I wanted individual total up_vote and down_vote not the total of both like you mentioned in your previous code : `total_upvote:{$sum:$upvote}`,`total_downvote:{$sum:$downvote}`

Comment: @RakshithaT.R Total of what exactly? The grouping is by category for the day and shows the total upvotes and downvotes for that combination. The only thing there is left to show a percentage of is the "total votes" The percentage of "total upvotes" to "total upvotes" is always 100%. Unless you are actually asking for the total percentage of **all** the results listed, which whilst possible is not practical. Think about it.

Comment: yes you are right but i need category downvote/upvote to total down /upvote like this `"upvote_percent": {
      "$multiply": [
        { "$divide": [ 
          "$categories.upvote", 
          "$total_upvote"
        ]},
        100
      ]
    }`

Comment: @RakshithaT.R Sorted. Needed to throw more data at it to make a sensible result.